# SELECT() next row in value assigning statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, select

I'm trying to select rows one by one in a while loop in SQL Server. And I'm using the only way I know to select the next row using `ROW_NUMBER` function. But I also have to assign values to t-sql variables in the same `SELECT` statement thus I'm getting the following error;

> A SELECT statement that assigns a value to a variable must not
>   be combined with data-retrieval operations.

Anyway my code is like this;

```
   WHILE (@i < 5)
   BEGIN
        SELECT -- This is where the error occurs
            @resultId = video.id, -- this is the value assigning i need to do
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY dateAdded DESC) AS ROWID
        FROM videoTest.dbo.video
        LEFT JOIN videoTest.dbo.aspnet_Users
        ON video.userId=aspnet_Users.UserId
        WHERE aspnet_Users.UserName=@searchUserName AND ROWID = @i

   -- Processing @resultId       
        SELECT
            compilationId
        FROM videoTest.dbo.comp
        WHERE vidId = @resultId -- i need the id from above
        ....
        ....
        ..... 
        ......

   @i = @i + 1
   END
```

I would be much appreciated if you can show me way to select next in an alternative way without getting this error, or a way to solve this error in my current code.
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to separate out the selection of the data from the retrieval of that data into a variable. You could use e.g. a CTE (Common Table Expression) to set up the data, and then operate on that data. However, on a more basic level : why are you assigning the `id` to `@resultId` five times?? You don't seem to be doing anything with the `@resultId` in the meantime.....

Could you change your logic to be more set-based ? Instead of a `WHILE` construct - just select the appropriate values from the CTE:

```
;WITH VideoData AS
(
    SELECT 
        video.id, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY dateAdded DESC) AS ROWID
    FROM 
        videoTest.dbo.video
    LEFT JOIN 
        videoTest.dbo.aspnet_Users ON video.userId = aspnet_Users.UserId
    WHERE 
        aspnet_Users.UserName = @searchUserName 
)
SELECT id, ROWID
FROM VideoData
WHERE ROWID <= 5
```

**Update:** if you need the five `video.id` values for later processing, try something like this:

```
DECLARE @VideoIDs TABLE (VideoID INT)

;WITH VideoData AS
(
   ... (same as before)
)
INSERT INTO @VideoIDs(VideoID)
   SELECT id
   FROM VideoData
   WHERE ROWID <= 5

-- use your values in the table variable here.....
```

Comment: the code continues from there and i'm using those 5 different video id's sorry for misunderstanding. I think this is what i'm looking for let me take my chances thanks!

Comment: sorry for not being clear enough earlier but i implemented your code but not quite found a way to access video.id on a latter statement. With CTE is there a way to save the video.id as a variable for future use? i need the @resultId for processes later, i've updated my code for my needs. Thank you!

Comment: @umutto: if you need it later, you need to stuff it into a table variable - the CTE is only valid for the immediate, next statement

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer! Then i think i should do so.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you need video.id. Why not just order by dateAdded, and store it in a cursor:

```
   SELECT
   INTO CURSOR @SomeCursor
    video.id
    FROM videoTest.dbo.video
    LEFT JOIN videoTest.dbo.aspnet_Users
    ON video.userId=aspnet_Users.UserId
    WHERE aspnet_Users.UserName=@searchUserName
    ORDER BY dateAdded DESC
```

and then iterate @SomeCursor?

Comment: EDIT: Oh sorry i've missed the cursor part can you please show a simple code for the cursor implementation.

Comment: You need ROWID or just the id?

Comment: no i just need id you're right i've misunderstood you on my first comment. Though i'm not familiar with usage of cursors. I'd appreciate a simple code block. Thanks!

Comment: Avoid cursor like the plague - you can, in at least 95% of the cases! Don't get used to cursors, they're a procedural RBAR (row-by-agonizing-row) kludge inside SQL Server. Use the set-based approach whenever possible - and it is possible, almost all the time...

Comment: Thanks Marc! i'll be using CTE and a temp table, and will take a look at cursor plague.